# How to use jQuery Components in Richfaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

I am new to richfaces.

I am not able to find a tutorial following which I can use jQuery Controls in Richfaces.

I was trying to follow 2 links

1. http://blog.bleathem.ca/2011/11/richfaces-4-cdk-jqeury-ui-tabs.html
2. http://planet.jboss.org/post/richfaces_4_cdk_jqeury_ui_tabs

I also tried to follow http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jQuery.jsf?c=jQuery&tab=usage but failed to get expected result.

Both written by same Author though.But am not able to find a conclusive idea of whole concept.

Comment: Which component exactly do you wish to use? Generally a combination of `<a4j:jsFunction>` and jQuery plugins are enough to make them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my eyes, the basic idea is to write his own components for Richfaces. The author of your articles created his own HTML output that meets the requirements for jQuery ui-tabs. He has just used the feature of Java to extends methods of JSF.

Comment: Yes, I agree, But is any other way out to use jquery with richfaces? I tried to follow http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jQuery.jsf?c=jQuery&tab=usage but result was not on expected lines

Comment: How should be the expected result?

Comment: Tabs as we expect in jQuery, but I was getting error, Am I requiered to use A4J:LoadScript? Am I required to add any specific Jar for this?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207901/richfaces-a4jloadscript-clears-jquery-plugins-on-ajax-calls will answer your question.

Comment: I found also a slow! website about it: http://ac.aua.am/Cis/Avsl/Literature/Jsf/ebooks/Ajax4JSF/ch06s14.html